# Ricci-flat metrics on complex tori of dimension $n \geq 3$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, kahler-manifolds, curvature

Let $\mathbb{T}^n = \mathbb{C}^n /\Lambda$ be a complex torus of (complex) dimension $n$. If $n=2$, it is a theorem of Berger that the Ricci-flat metrics on $\mathbb{T}^2$ are flat. This follows from the Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem and the fact that the Euler characteristic of $\mathbb{T}^2$ is zero.

> Are there Ricci-flat metrics on $\mathbb{T}^{n \geq 3}$ that are not flat?

Comment: I'm guess you are asking about Ricci flat Kähler metrics?

Comment: The answer is no, see e.g. https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1974-80-01/S0002-9904-1974-13368-9/S0002-9904-1974-13368-9.pdf, 
The Calabi construction for compact Ricci flat Riemannian manifolds, Arthur E. Fischer and Joseph A. Wolf,  Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 80 (1974), 92-97. The fact the torus is complex is not relevant.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Thank you, I have heard Berger's result mentioned time and time again, but surprisingly was never made aware of this result of Fischer and Wolf. Thank you!

Comment: More generally one can appeal to Cheeger-Gromoll splitting that says that the universal Riemannian cover of a compact manifold $M$ of nonnegative Ricci curvature splits isometrically as the product of a Euclidean space and a compact simply-connected manifold of nonnegative Ricci curvature.  If $M$ is diffeomorphic to an $n$-torus, the simply-connected factor is a point and hence $M$ is locally isometric to $\mathbb R^n$.